# AngularJS $parse TypeError: object is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I have stripped my app down to the bare bones but I keep getting this error when using $parse: **TypeError: object is not a function**

What is wrong? What am I missing?

Seems to work fine in this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/WrXv9hT5YA0xYcLLvyDb
Could parse be conflicting with some other module?

Weirder still - it actually does change the value of $scope.modal.on! Even though it appears to die before hand...

```
/* Controllers */

//var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.sortable']);
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);


MyApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', '$modal', '$parse', function($scope, $http, $parse, $modal, $log) {



    $scope.modal = { 
        open    : false,
        tplfile : null,
        toggle  : function(){ 
            this.open = !this.open; 
            if(this.open) angular.element('body').addClass('modal-open');
            else          angular.element('body').removeClass('modal-open');
        }   
    };

        var modal = $parse('modal.open');
        modal.assign($scope, true);

}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You passed in your dependencies in the incorrect order.  The dependencies to the function have to match exactly the order in the array.

```
MyApp.controller('MyController', 
['$scope', '$http', '$modal', '$parse', function
($scope, $http, $parse, $modal, $log) {
```

If you swap `$parse` and `$modal` in your controller declaration, your error will go away.  Also, you are missing `$log`, if you try to use that dependency you will get an error as well.

Comment: That worked, it was the order. And you won by about 30 secs ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
['$scope', '$http', '$modal', '$parse', function($scope, $http, $parse, $modal,
```

The `$parse` and `$modal` are interchanged.

Please correct the order and it will work :)

It should be

```
MyApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', '$modal', '$parse', '$log', function($scope, $http,  $modal, $parse, $log) {
```

Comment: You're totally right, that worked. But Claies edged you out by 30 secs. ;) Thanks!