# Error: undefined is not an object?

Tags: angularjs

I am having trouble figuring out what's the error here. Can anyone help me? I'm new to Angular.
Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Logging.initLogComponent')

```
 14 app.factory('Logging', function($fileLogger, $filter) {
 15   var today = new Date();  
 16   today = $filter('date')(today, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
 17 
 18   
 19   return {
 20     initLogComponent : function() { 
 21       fileName = today;      
 22       $fileLogger.setStorageFilename(fileName);
 23       console.log('Current log file: ' + fileName);
 24       $fileLogger.setTimestampFormat('medium');
 25     }
 26   };
 27 });
 28 
 29 app.controller('loggingController', ['$scope', '$fileLogger', '$timeout', function($scope, $fileLogger, $timeout, Logging){                                                                             
 30   Logging.initLogComponent();
 31   
 32   
 33 }]);
```

Comment: not exactly the same code but this is your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28893148/angularjs-parse-typeerror-object-is-not-a-function/28893229#28893229

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You havent added `Logging` dependency correctly in your controller

Change your controller to this:

```
app.controller('loggingController', ['$scope', '$fileLogger', '$timeout', 'Logging', function($scope, $fileLogger, $timeout, Logging){                                                                             
    Logging.initLogComponent();
}]);
```

**Notice how I've passed one extra parameter `'Logging'` in your controller.** It is different from the the parameter that's passed in your function.

Comment: Hey, how come whenever i add a default argument parameter to the function initLogComponent and i get this error message:  Argument 'loggingController' is not a function, got undefined? For example initLogComponent : function(fileName = today)

Comment: hey what's the problem here?

Comment: @MuhammadBinladen Whatever you've mentioned in your comment is completely valid statement [as you can see in this example Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/A6NWtk5SCXgF5XzxNimu?p=preview). Please post your complete code as a separate question so we can look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a type of DateTime in a string without casting it to a string first, try:

```
var stringDate = today.ToString();
```